# Automatic run of shell script with screencapture

Tags: terminal, automator, screen-capture

I am trying to automate a screen capturing of my machine.
The issue I had is no software out there (I have found so far) cannot screen all monitors at once.

I ended up with a shell script, that is creating the folder structure I need and inside, it screens all monitors by screen capture utility and then merges them to one image with ImageMagick utility, then performs some cleanup, etc.
This happens every minute.

When I run this shell manually, everything works just fine, the terminal window is running from the dock, and it captures everything.
But what I want to achieve is to run this script at startup.

And that is where I am stuck:

- adding the shell script itself to startup items won't work, the script will never run.
- Creating an Automator app has the access issue. Even though I have Automator main app AND the generated compiled workflow app AND terminal app added to the permission for screen recording, the system pops up the permission box each and every time the shell script will try to perform a screenshot. Additionally, strangely, when I have my Automator open (main app) and I try to RUN the workflow, nothing happens. It just runs the script (which is an infinite loop of actions) but it will never perform any action from the script (folder creation, screen capturing...)
- Running the shell as service is not working either, I have created plist record in Library, and I know the script is running because it does create new folders, but the screen capture will never happen, even though, again, the terminal app is allowed for screen recording.

Please, does anyone have any idea, how to run my (fully working) shell script automatically with actually it doing what it should do?

Thank you!

Comment: Do your screens form a coherent rectangle when viewed in System Prefs > Displays > Arrangement? If so you can skip a step & capture all displays in a single image, right from the shellscript. idk what happens if they don't form a rectangle, but you could always try it. e.g. `do shell script "screencapture -R 0,0,5120,1440  /Users/me/Desktop/test.png"`

Comment: BTW, rather than using Automator, just write the script in Script Editor, then save as an app. The app can then be set as a startup item. [You might need to put a delay at the start of the script so it waits for the machine to have got everything on screen up & running].